# Retry the preparedstatement batches if an exception (SQLException | BatchUpdateException) occurs - Java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I had a situation where my code was getting hit by the deadlock issue with SQL Server for some transactions. So, I implemented a retry logic to overcome the same. Now, I'm facing a new problem. The problem is, whenever it retries, the batch which was tried to execute will be empty/cleared after recovering from the exception. This is causing missing data inserts/updates. Please help me with this.

Summary:
Retry the preparedstatement batches if an exception (SQLException | BatchUpdateException) occurs

Current Implementation:

```
do {
        try {
            if (isInsert) {
                int[] insertRows = psInsert.executeBatch();
                psInsert.clearBatch();
                System.out.println("insertRowsSuccess:" + Arrays.toString(insertRows));
            } else {
                int[] updateRows = psUpdate.executeBatch();
                psUpdate.clearBatch();
                System.out.println("updateRowsSuccess:" + Arrays.toString(updateRows));
            }
            break;
        } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
            conn.rollback();
            if (++count == maxTries) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                getFailedRecords(e, operation);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (++count == maxTries) {
                System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Tries:" + count);
    } while (true);
    

private static void getFailedRecords(BatchUpdateException ex, String operation) {

    int[] updateCount = ex.getUpdateCounts();
    ArrayList<Integer> failedRecsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int failCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < updateCount.length; i++) {
        if (updateCount[i] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
            failCount++;
            failedRecsList.add(i);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(operation + " Failed Count: " + failCount);
    System.out.println(operation + " FailedRecordsIndex:" + failedRecsList);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After execute, irrespective of success or failure of the batch, the batch will be cleared. You will need to repopulate the batch before you can retry.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. I have been thinking of this solution lately. However, in the current system/pattern does not allow me to rebuild the batch. I'm expected to either retain the batch somehow, clone it before the execution or fail it in the second try as well so that it catches the exception. In this case, it just executes and returns an empty array when retried. Hence, no exception is caught while retrying.

Comment: @sree_me If you can't rebuild the batch, it would be better to execute the statements individually.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just move the `clearBatch()` outside of the `try`. If you have to recheck whether it's an insert or update, so be it. If `psInsert` and `psUdate` are the same class, or derive from the same base class (and it sounds like they should), you can easily call it in a separate one liner method.

I also think if you submit this question to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you'd get some good suggestions to improve the code. I'm not saying it's terrible, but I think there's room for improvement in the underlying model. I'm not familiar enough with Java, though.

Comment: thank you for your response. I shall try your suggestion. I have also submitted the same to code review. Hopefully, I be able to get the solution/tips soon.

Comment: A `executeBatch` will automatically clear the batch before it returns. The fact there is a `clearBatch()` inside the `try` is irrelevant: it will not be executed when the `BatchUpdateException` is thrown. To retry, the batch needs to be populated again.